# What is the best way to select one row in MySQL using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, row, fetch

I have a mysql statement which grabs just one record based on an id. I want to know if using mysql_fetch_row or something along the lines of that is better then using something such as mysql_fetch_array, for just grabbing one row in a database.

It may seem like common sense to go with the mysql_fetch_row but I just want to make sure.

Comment: What's the cause of concern for choosing between the two? a 73 microsecond speedup? If you're just choosing between fetching associative and numerically indexed arrays, just use whichever's easier to work with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> An important thing to note is that
>   using `mysql_fetch_array()` is ***not***
>   ***significantly*** slower than using
>   `mysql_fetch_row()`, while it provides a
>   significant added value.

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just use `LIMIT 1` inside the mysql statement and no matter what you will have one row.

Comment: Presumably if he knows the `id` then his query already looks like `WHERE id = 'foo'`

Comment: @Bacon what does that have to do with `limit 1`?

Comment: I think Bacon Bits is assuming that `id` is unique, which it sounds like it is.

Comment: @Wiseguy, what does it have to do with id??? the OP just wants the 1st line, so it doesn't matter...

Comment: That comment was in regard to your question about @Bacon Bits' comment, not your answer. Rephrased above.

Comment: @Neal if `id` is unique, there's either going to be 1 or 0, there's no need for a `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: @Neal Yes, I'm assuming `id` is a [primary] key.  There's nothing wrong with `LIMIT` but there's no reason to include it in a query which by definition is only going to return a single record.  It's extraneous and a possible waste of the server's time.

Answer (score 0):

The two functions are almost identical, the name is just making you think it's different:

```
$r=mysql_query('SELECT name,email FROM tbl LIMIT 1');
var_dump(mysql_fetch_assoc($r));
    // array('name'=>[dbName], 'email'=>[dbEmail]);
var_dump(mysql_fetch_row($r));
    // array([dbName], [dbEmail]);
    // It's a normal incremental integer index array
var_dump(mysql_fetch_array($r,MYSQL_ASSOC));
    // same as mysql_fetch_assoc();
var_dump(mysql_fetch_array($r,MYSQL_NUM));
    // same as mysql_fetch_row();
var_dump(mysql_fetch_array($r,MYSQL_BOTH));
    // array(0=>[dbName], 1=>[dbEmail], 'name'=>[dbName], 'email'=>[dbEmail]);
```

The manual also suggests performance wise the two functions fared well. Local tests hint in the same direction. I'd suggest you not worry about the .0001 time/memory saved and find true bottlenecks in your applications.